# FTP to a subfolder

Tags: php, ftp, cron

Is it possible to upload a file into a subfolder on an FTP server?

I send a file daily to an FTP server, scheduled on a cron job that runs a php file. It all works fine, but now I've been asked to change the destination to a subfolder.

Changing *$server_name = 'ftp.website.com'* to *$server_name = 'ftp.website.com/data'* 
doesn't seem to work?

I can see the folder exists in filezilla and it has all read/write access in permissions.

I'd be grateful if someone can advise if its a permission issue or whether it's possible at all?

Thanks in advance.

CODE...

```
//FTP bit...

$server_name        = 'ftp.website.com';
$server_username    = 'xxxx';
$server_password    = 'xxxx';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($server_name);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $server_username, $server_password);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
ftp_put($conn_id, $zip_filename, $output_dir . $zip_filename, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: You are probably looking for [`ftp_chdir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php), I suspect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you need to use [`ftp_chdir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php).

Connect as normal, and then change directories using `ftp_chdir()`.

Comment: Thanks SenorAmor. I changed the bottom to: ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/data');
ftp_put($conn_id, $txt_filename, $output_dir . $txt_filename, FTP_BINARY); which has worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the ftp functions of PHP. I see two options:

1) Use `ftp_put` and specify the absolute path on the ftp server. http://php.net/manual/de/function.ftp-put.php

2) Before uploading your file change the working directory on the ftp server using `ftp_chdir` http://php.net/manual/de/function.ftp-chdir.php

Comment: Thanks signpainter for the guidance. I changed the bottom to: ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/data');
ftp_put($conn_id, $txt_filename, $output_dir . $txt_filename, FTP_BINARY); which has worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ftp_put` you simply specify the absolute destination path on the server

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php